# How to call sum function in parallel threads and pass the numbers from array to function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parallel-processing

I'm doing a small task in Python:

1- write a simple add function that will add two given numbers and print their sum.

2- Declare an array of 10 numbers.

3- call sum function in parallel threads and pass the numbers form above array to function as per following rules:

--> sum(array[thread_id], array[9-thread_id])

I have done step 1 and step 2 but I don't know what to do in step 3. Here's the code below:

```
import array
import multiprocessing
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process

# 1- write a simple add function that will add two given numbers and print their sum

x = 5
y = 10

def add(a,b):
    sum = int(a) + int(b)
    print ("The sum is: ", sum)
    
add(x,y)
    
# 2 Declare an array of 10 numbers
a_list = list(range(1, 11))
print ('an array of 10 numbers: '  + str(a_list))





# 3 call sum function in parallel threads and pass the numbers form above array to function as per following rules

# --> sum(array[thread_id], array[9-thread_id])
```

Can anyone please help me with what to do in step 3?
I have little knowledge of parallel threads (or multiprocessing)

Answer (score 2):

In Python, you can start a new thread like so

```py
import threading

def function_to_run_in_thread(arg1, arg2): ...

threading.Thread(target=function_to_run_in_thread, args=("some", "arguments")).start()
```

and you can start a new process similarly like so

```py
import multiprocessing

def function_to_run_in_subprocess(arg1, arg2): ...

multiprocessing.Process(target=function_to_run_in_subprocess, args=("some", "arguments")).start()
```

however, it is not particularly easy to get at the function return value by threading/multiprocessing in this way. It would be better to use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` or `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` module.

so in your case we can do

```py
# Both the ThreadPoolExecutor and ProcessPoolExecutor are basically interchangeable from an API perspective
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor as Pool
# from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor as Pool

pool = Pool(10) # the argument is the number of threads/processes available

sum_futures = [pool.submit(add, *pair) for pair in zip(a_list, reversed(a_list))]

# We must explicitly wait for the calculation to finish for each add call
sum_results = [future.result() for future in sum_futures]
```

Or, we can also do

```py
sum_results = list(pool.map(lambda args: add(*args), zip(a_list, reversed(a_list))))
```

to be more concise

---

In CPython (the reference implementation of Python, and the one that you're probably using), only one thread can be holding the Global Interpreter Lock at a given time. This means that multithreading in code running in the CPython interpreter only gives you a benefit for doing operations that do not require holding the GIL, such as

- blocking network/IO operations
- running certain code in a C extension that explicitly releases the GIL

Basically what this means is that the operation of adding two numbers together in python cannot truly execute in parallel when using multithreading.

However, mulitprocessing comes with its own drawbacks, one of which being that serialization (using `pickle`) is required to pass values between processes. Some values cannot be pickled (e.g lambda expressions), which can be a potential roadblock. Threads are not subject to this restriction because they can communicate over using shared regions of memory, which is also a lot faster.

Comment: I executed what you provided above but got an error saying:

' AttributeError: 'Pool' object has no attribute 'submit'  '

Comment: There should be a `submit` method on the `ThreadPoolExecutor` object [link to python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.submit)

Comment: Ok, I sorted this out, and the python file is executed successfully. 
My output: is  ' The sum is:  11 ........ The sum is: 11 '